# Expression Simplification Algorithm

Tags: math, expression, calculator

I'm currently working on a Calculator app and I want output to be in both a simplified expression and decimal answer form. An example would be sqrt 2 * sqrt 3 = sqrt 6 which can also be outputted as 2.44948... What is the best approach to this and is there any well-established algorithms to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  What you likely want is a [computer algebra system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system), which understands formulas as artifacts to be manipulated by explicit mathematics rules.

Mathematica and Macsyma are applications which do this.  However, these are quite sophisticated systems and it is not easy to see how they "work".

What you need to do is:

- Represent formulas as abstract syntax trees
- Parse text formulas (your example equations) into such trees
- Encode a set of tree-manipulation rules that represent algebra operations
- Apply these rules to your algebra trees
- Prettyprint the algebra trees back as text when done

Rules are best written in the surface syntax of algebra.  (Mathematica doesn't do this; it represents formulas as trees using a kind of prefix S-expressions, and rules as the same kind of trees with special variable nodes).

One of the issues is deciding how many "algebra" rules you are wiling to encode.  Mathematics is a lot more than pure 9th grade algebra, and people using such systems tend to want to extend what is there by adding more knowledge (the point of Mathematica and Macsyma: they are infinitely extendable).

Here's a very simple version of this.  You can see all the "gears" and how things are described, in terms of parse trees and rewrite rules.

http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html

Comment: @Scheff:  thanks for  pointing that out.  (Suprised that SO doesn't check them).  Fixed.

Comment: Could you outline how the actual simplification might work? One could define a cost function which maps an expression to it's perceived complexity - But which approaches can be used to minimize this cost function?

Comment: @NyxMC: Fundamentally you have a "search" problem:  you have a "search state" consisting of an equation, and "operators" which are simplification rewrite rules.  The search problem is classically to enumerate the space of all possible operator sequences applied to the original state, and choose the "best" state (smallest resulting expression counting operators and operands).  You can actually implement this in a brute force way, but that's often far too expensive in practice.  People have invented many better methods; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_search for an introduction.

Comment: ... a common trick for expression simplification is to write simplification rules that only make the expression shorter, then apply all rewrite rules exhaustively until no more apply.  Given that each rewrite rule successfully applied shortens the answer, its clear that this scheme always terminates and it does so pretty quickly.  This is the method used in the SimpleDMSDomain example above.  It does not guarantee an an optimal or even a really good result, but in general it works pretty well.

Comment: Sophisticated computer algebra systems, and digital circuit design systems, are often built with much cleverer search algorithms so that they in fact produce something closer to optimal than the simple hill-climbing ("shorten the expression") search I described in the previous comment.

Comment: Makes sense (though I would have expected there to be a more efficient approach).
Another question about this came to mind: A single rule might be applicable in more than one place within an expression. Does it make sense to model every possible application of the rule as an edge in the state space graph? Or is it enough to apply the rule to the AST of the expression bottom-up or top-down?

Comment: An example: For the expression `(a * a) * (a * a)`, the rule `(x * x) <=> (x ^ 2)` could be applied top-down (`(a * a) * (a * a)` -> `(a * a) ^ 2` -> `(a ^ 2) ^ 2`) or bottom-up (`(a * a) * (a * a)` -> `(a ^ 2) * (a ^ 2)` -> `(a ^ 2) ^ 2`).

Comment: You've observed that sometimes you can apply rules in different orders and achieve the same effect.   Really smart simplifiers know this and only apply such rules in a particular order because that significantly shrinks the search space.   But in general, you have an arbitrarily hard search problem if you are looking to a near-optimal solution.   There's a huge literature (see Wikipedia article above for starting place) on how to implement searches that are more efficient by harnessing such knowledge.